# Is officially allowed to use parentheses to call ANY callable type in PHP?

Tags: php, callable

The PHP documentation says:

> [...] if a variable name has parentheses appended to it, PHP will look for a function with the same name as whatever the variable evaluates to, and will attempt to execute it.

This is about named functions. Parentheses also works with Closures, and this is widely used (backward compatibility with the old lambda functions).

Currently, this works too (with PHP 5.4):

```
$method = [$oObject, "methodName"];
$result = $method($param1, $param2);
```

But this is not documented, and my hands "tingle" when I write it.

Is there any guarantee that this will keep to work in the future (not need to use call_user_func() etc.)?

Is this safe:

```
public function apply(callable $any_callable_variant)
{
    return $any_callable_variant($this);
}
```

There are precedents, then not-documented-but-useful features was removed from PHP.

**Update: one more thing**

Some comments (already deleted) mentioned the `callable` pseudotype.

Documentation says about `is_callable`:

> Verify that the contents of a variable can be called as a function.
>   This can check that a simple variable contains the name of a valid
>   function, or that an array contains a properly encoded object and
>   function name.

According to this, a `Closure` is not callable (not true, of course). Make a test:

```
var_dump(is_callable(function () { // prints: bool(true)
    return false;
}, true, $callable_name));

var_dump($callable_name); // prints: string(17) "Closure::__invoke"
```

It seems, no one even thought about the documentation when `Closure` was introduced.

Comment: the [manual about 'Callback's'](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) explains the various ways of calling PHP methods and functions. Your '$method = [$oObject, "methodName"];' is just a standard way of calling a named method of an 'object' instance.

Comment: This way of calling a method is already working for a long time

Comment: In fact, this works. But not documented or indicated. No sign, than it is absolutely safe.

Comment: This is about the callable pseudotype (type hinting), not about the parentheses syntax.

Comment: This sentence (also quoted by me) is not clear. Is `[$oObject, "methodName"]` a "function name"? No. (Not speaking about Closures.)